# Lync 2013 SDK video on Server 2008 R2

Tags: lync

I have used the Lync 2013 SDK to make a restricted client. When I install it on server2008 R2 the videopart does not work. When hooking up with a client I can see that the video is sent and when "unsuppressing" lync I can see that the normal Lync client shows the video..

So the problem is in the renderwindow in the api.

Any suggestions?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows the specified video window in the specified panel.
    /// </summary>
    private static void ShowVideo(Panel videoPanel, VideoWindow videoWindow)
    {
        //Win32 constants:                  WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS;
        const long lEnableWindowStyles = 0x40000000L | 0x02000000L | 0x04000000L;
        //Win32 constants:                   WS_POPUP| WS_CAPTION | WS_SIZEBOX
        const long lDisableWindowStyles = 0x80000000 | 0x00C00000 | 0x00040000L;
        const int OATRUE = -1;

        try
        {
            //sets the properties required for the native video window to draw itself
            videoWindow.Owner = videoPanel.Handle.ToInt32();
            videoWindow.SetWindowPosition(0, 0, videoPanel.Width, videoPanel.Height);

            //gets the current window style to modify it
            long currentStyle = videoWindow.WindowStyle;

            //disables borders, sizebox, close button
            currentStyle = currentStyle & ~lDisableWindowStyles;

            //enables styles for a child window
            currentStyle = currentStyle | lEnableWindowStyles;

            //updates the current window style
            videoWindow.WindowStyle = (int)currentStyle;

            //updates the visibility
            videoWindow.Visible = OATRUE;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, or does the video just not show in the video window. How are you setting the video window, can you post code?

Comment: I have just added the code.. I do not get any errors, just a gray boks at the top of the panel, or if i use the videowindow from the api, just a white square.. But at the other end I can see the video stream if I use the lync client.